# trying to install wine5 on debian 10: "unmet dependencies: winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.1~buster)"

Tags: debian, wine, debian-buster

i want wine5 on a brand new debian 10.5 system,

i followed the instructions here https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian ,

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386;
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key -O- | sudo apt-key add - ;
printf "\n#wine\ndeb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ buster main\n" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list ;
sudo apt update;
```

no errors, everything went smoothly,

then on the very last step:

```
root@debgamer:/home/hans# sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable;
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.1~buster)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@debgamer:/home/hans#
```

now what?

and just in case it's relevant,

```
root@debgamer:/home/hans# apt policy winehq-stable
winehq-stable:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.0.1~buster
  Version table:
     5.0.1~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     5.0.0~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.4~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.3~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.2~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     4.0.1~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     4.0~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.5~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.4~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.3~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.2~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.1~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     3.0.0~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.4~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.3~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.2~buster 500
        500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
```

says 5.0.1 is available (and even that it's the preferred version, it seems)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from your [link](https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian):

> The WineHQ packages for Debian 10 and later require libfaudio0 as a dependency. Since the distro does not provide it for Debian 10, users of that version can download libfaudio0 packages from the OBS. See https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=32192 for details.

Libfaudio0 might be the dependency you are missing.

Comment: huh, the people in the forum suggest adding an OpenSUSE repo in Debian, that doesn't really sound particularly safe, Debian and OpenSUSE are quite different distros :o

Comment: That advice was only in case of conflicts. You should prefer the [Debian 10 repository](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/Debian_10/) link in the article.